# Unknown Provider Error, Dependency Injection, Modal Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am attempting to build a custom modal service to accept data and produce a modal with those inputs; however, I am receiving the unknown provider error is Angular when passing the literal identifier of the controller to the `controller` property of the modal.

I've got dependency injection working elsewhere in my application; it is only failing, here. There are a number of questions on SO dealing with this issue, I know; however, out of those that I have read, I am unable to find a more generic answer that might begin to point me in the right direction.

Here is my service code:

```
angular.module('app').service('CustomModalService', ['$uibModal', function ($uibModal) {

    this.openCustomModal = function (size, title, message, action) {
        var actionToPerformOnConfirm = action;

        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'templates/CustomModal.html',
            controller: 'CustomModalInstanceController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            size: size,
            resolve: {
                content: function () {
                    return {
                        title: title,
                        message: message
                    };
                }
            }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function (actionToPerformOnConfirm) {
            console.log('something happened');
        }.bind(this));
    };
}]);
```

And here is the modal Controller, referenced, above:

```
angular.module('app').controller('CustomModalInstanceController', function ($uibModalInstance, content) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.title = content.title;
    vm.message = content.message;

    $scope.confirmAction = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.close();
    };

    $scope.cancelAction = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
```

This should be enough from what I understand of Angular. **Everything works in this service, otherwise**, if the controller reference is removed.

There's even [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487259/the-correct-way-to-inject-an-angular-controller-dependency-inside-an-angular-ui) (a great summation of all the questions I have encountered) which corroborates the documentation and the numerous examples I have seen online; yet, I am still getting the unknown provider error. This user even asks the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432592/ui-bootstrap-modals-controller-is-not-defined) (again, from what I can see, my code is a shining example of "correct")!

To show that both are in the same directory, here is a picture of the directory structure:

[image]

Where do I need to begin to look to resolve this issue? Is this an application configuration issue?

Comment: unknown provider errors are usually due to services or controller not being found, are your service and controller in different directories?

Comment: @ManuAntony they are in the same directory, here. They do get spat out into a minified file. Will post image of directory structure if that is helpful?

Comment: that would be helpful also how is your app piecing together the controllers?, from the looks of it your controller is undefined within your app, try restarting your dev environment if you just added the controller

Comment: @ManuAntony actually, that's a good question. I am newer to Angular scene. The original architect looks to have included a `routes.js` file with calls to an injected `$stateProvider`. Here, templates are mapped to controllers. The odd thing is I have not had to modify this file for the inclusion of my service (don't know if that is normal). If the controlled is not registered here, could that be the culprit?

Comment: It could be, usually most web apps specify the controllers used by the app somewhere like a config setting.  Most cases the culprit is not loading the controllers for your app as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15244272/angularjs-error-unknown-provider

Comment: The original error is the most useful piece of every error-related question, you haven't posted it.

Comment: @Thomas Can you show how you're injecting a controller within that module?  A controller is not injected the same way as other components.

Comment: @dmcqu314 what you see is what you get :) I haven't done anything else to support the injection. Sounds like I am missing something?

Comment: my question might sound silly, but can you check the params passed into the controller are in the right way? `$uibModalInstance, content` . Or better yet can you remove everything in the controller just a empty controller no params  and see if you are still getting the error?

Comment: @ManuAntony definitely something with params. Good call. Thought I tried that approach. I think it might be the inject syntax surrounding `$uibModalInstance`. I'll get back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question, in great thanks to Manu Antony for working with me. The problem was not the injection of the controller, itself, but rather with the parameters supplied to the controller.

In the end, it was a syntactical error on my part.

Here is the correct controller signature syntax (I added scope for fun):

```
angular.module('app').controller('CustomModalInstanceController', ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', 'content', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, content) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

When I do encounter these issues, they are very frustrating. The steps I take to resolve these issues are to go back to the script tag in the html and make sure the ID is the same as the templateUrl. So here i am showing you where i create my modal:

```
  var editPatient = $uibModal.open({    //Here is where the modal gets created. you set the html page and the controller
        templateUrl: 'EditPatientData.html',
        controller: 'EditPatientData',
        size: size,
        resolve: {
            data: function () {
                return angular.copy(patientModel);
            }
        }
    });
```

Now Below I am showing you the code in my Html file that maps to the code above. Make sure the ID in the script tag is exactly the same in your js. (I suggest you use copy and paste to avoid spelling errors.)

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="EditPatientData.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Edit Patient Data</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
     //whatever you want to display
    </div>
</script>
```

Hopefully this answers your question. If you need any more help, or more specification, do not hesitate to ask. :)

Comment: not sure if this would solve it as the OP suggested ** Everything works in this service, otherwise, if the controller reference is removed. ** , i'm guessing the controller is at fault

Comment: @ManuAntony When i encounter many of the Same issues he is talking about, those are the main points I look for and try to fix. He should try what I stated and see what happens.

Comment: @James can you post your controller? I am having trouble passing data from the modal service to the controller

Comment: @Thomas just to clarify, which controller do you want? The main controller or the modal controller?

Comment: @James modal. If you could look at my example, too, that would be great. The problem I am having is getting the params. to resolve